# spring-cloud-starter-oauth2 how to allow register api

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-oauth2

I've been trying to create the Authorization Server and Resources Server using spring-cloud-starter-oauth2 and it works well but the problems is I can't register news user using an api /register even though I config the SecurityConfig like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

}
```

Here is the api

```
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RegisterController {

    /**
     * Logger
     */
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BookController.class);

    /**
     * UserService
     */
    private RegisterService registerService;

    /**
     * Register new normal user to the system
     *
     * @param userRegisterDto
     * @return Response
     * @throws BadRequestException
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Response registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody final UserRegisterDto userRegisterDto) throws BadRequestException, Exception {
        try {
            LOG.info("Start register new user by UserRegisterDto");
            if (!userRegisterDto.getPassword().equals(userRegisterDto.getPasswordConfirmation())) {
                LOG.warn("Password confirmation does not match with password");
                throw new BadRequestException(ResponseMessage.PasswordConfirmationDoesNotMatch);
            }
            registerService.registerUser(userRegisterDto);
            LOG.info("End register new user by UserRegisterDto");
        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            throw new BadRequestException(ResponseMessage.NotFoundRoleWithRoleName);
        } catch (DataDuplicatedException e) {
            throw new BadRequestException(ResponseMessage.DuplicatedValue, userRegisterDto.getUsername());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BadRequestException(ResponseMessage.InvalidAccessError);
        }
        Response response = new Response();
        response.setHttpStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED);
        return response;
    }

}
```

The message I got is

```
{
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}
```